# How to fix the error that I get using MySQL LOAD INFILE?

Tags: sql, mysql, load-data-infile

I have a products table  with the following structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (

  `id` int(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `productname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `merchanturl` text NOT NULL,
  `imageurl` text NOT NULL,
  `price` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `original` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `currency` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `extrafields` text NOT NULL,
  `feedid` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `merchant` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `productname` (`productname`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `description` (`description`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

I use mysql `LOAD INFILE` command to import delimited data files into this table. It has 4 million records now. When I import more data using `LOAD INFILE` I get the following error:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

I am not able to access the products table after that.
How can I improve the performance of the table? Note that some data files are more than 100MB in size. I have another 4 million entries which need to be 
imported to the table.

Please suggest methods to avoid these issues.

Thanks,
Sree

Comment: Are you able to connect to mysql server at all or are you getting the ERROR 2002 in the middle of loading the file?

Comment: some times it happends in the middle of loading file. After that i am not able to run queries on that table. i have use myisamchk to repair the table to access it

Answer (score 0):

Try connect to mysql server using TCP/IP instead of socket.  Socket is only available for unix like operating system.

Comment: this is a Linux Server and I am using the LOAD INFILE query from the shell script